# Identify the left and right part of the decimal (varchar)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to transform varchar values like this `1250` to decimal values `12.50`.

Some examples :

```
16500 165.00
17525 175.25
1015  10.15
 955  9.55
```

I actually use this to do it `stuff(@total,len(@total)-1,0,'.')` and then insert my value to a decimal column in my table. This works until the varchar value is more than `100` = `1.00`. Actually if I get a value like `5` = `0.05` (5 cents) I have an issue and it doesnt work. It must also works with negative values like `-3` = `-0.03`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the TRY_CAST function?
Something like

```
    SELECT TRY_CAST('1625' AS float) / 100
    FROM yourtable
```

Edit:
Even better :)

```
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@total) = 1
         THEN TRY_CAST(@total AS float) / 100
         ELSE 'NOT NUMERIC'
        END AS Total
    FROM yourtable
```